# Calling an object's method in different ways

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here's the code:
JavaScript part:

```
    ContatoreCostr = function(nome){
      this.nome = nome;
      this.cont = 0;
      this.inc = function() {
        alert(this + "--" + this.nome + "--" + this.cont++);
      };
    }
    var ccc=  new ContatoreCostr("zio");

window.onload = function() {
    //document.getElementById("bid").onclick = ccc.inc; // DO NOT WORK
    document.getElementById("bid").onclick = function(){ccc.inc()};  //WORKS
}
```

HTML part:

```
<button onClick="ccc.inc()">Buttton1</button>  
<button id="bid">Bottone2</button>
```

Here are two different ways to call the same method inside the same object, in fact `cont` property continue to be incremented whatever button is clicked. The context change: it is window when Button1 is clicked, and tagButton when Button2 is pressed but that's fine.
I do not understand why I'm forced to assign `onclick` to `function(){ccc.inc()}` instead of `ccc.inc` that. In my mind there should be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The first method the () are missing?
It should be

```
document.getElementById("bid").onclick = ccc.inc();
```

Comment: No, if you put the parenthesis inc() is evaluated when you load the page, that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

"this" only works when the function has been called directly by the "instance", like in ccc.inc(). When passed as reference "this" refers to calling context, in this case the clickable element.

Comment: ok so you say: in the 'do not work' case inc() is called int the context of 'this' that is buttonTag. As opposite the 'works' case should work like this: buttonTag is this. The interpreter consider load ccc, that is the object previusly instantiated, then invoke inc() on ccc. It makes sense. Actually it took some time to me to figure out the 'works' solution, i proceded by trials and errors and I still can't figure out a sequence of logical steps to design the 'works' solution. I would be grateful to anyone capable to recommend a documentation deep enough. Thank you.

Comment: er... yes, not works case executes in context of the calling object, that's the clicked element. There seem to be plenty of explanations about this in internet, look for example here: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Comment: I edited my post. I can't give you a deep explanation since the concept is only superficially clear for me now. I'll also read the documentation when I have time ^^